# Google Analytic Figures Don't Add Up

Tags: google-analytics

Some rounded down figures:

- Total users for August were 15,000
- Total users for Sept were 16,000
- Adding these two = 31000 users

However, when we look at total users for Aug 1-Sept 30 we get 30,000

Why the difference of 1000? Does this suggest only 1k users are returning?

Am I off, or is this quite a low figure for users who used the site in BOTH months?

Answer (score 3):

When you request a report, Analytics looks up each metric in the pre-aggregated data tables and serves those results to your reports. If you adjust the date range from August 1st - August 31st to August 1st - September 1st, Analytics looks up each metric in the September 1st pre-aggregated data table and adds the new data to the existing total.

This works well for most metrics. Many metrics, like Pageviews or Screenviews, are simple additive counts over days. However, Users is based on more complicated calculations. Instead of simply adding (or subtracting) processed data from the pre-aggregated tables, Analytics must recalculate Users for each date range that you select in a report.

For example, if a user visits a website on August 31 and on September 1, Analytics recognizes this user as a single user over the course of these two days. If you change your date range from August 1st - August 31st to August 1st - September 1st, Analytics can’t simply add the difference to the value of Users you see in your reports because this number is based on a complicated calculation, and not just added to the running total in the pre-aggregated data tables. Instead, the metric has to be calculated on the fly each time you request it in your reports.

Check out this link for more in-depth info and how to address this challenge. 
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2992042?hl=en